# GET params not accessible in Java servlet class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have just started with J2EE and servlet programming and fell into this little trouble. Here is my code - 
My servlet class code
    package PackageServer;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
//import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class PostServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public PostServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");

      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      String title = "Using GET Method to Read Form Data";
      String docType =
      "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 " +
      "transitional//en\">\n";

      out.println(docType +
                "<html>\n" +
                "<head><title>" + title + "</title></head>\n" +
                "<body bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\n" +
                "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + "</h1>\n" +
                "<ul>\n" +
                "  <li><b>First Name</b>: "
                + request.getParameter("first_name") + "\n" +
                "  <li><b>Last Name</b>: "
                + request.getParameter("last_name") + "\n" +
                "</ul>\n" +
                "</body></html>");
      out.println("<h1>Hello</h1>");
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
/*protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}*/
```

}

Now my params in HTML file are first_name and last_name. I have correctly specified the url-pattern in web xml file to be the name of my servlet class but still when I run my project the server responds with a 404 not found and then displays the view with servlet output where first_name and last_name are set to null. What am I doing wrong in here ?

Comment: Don't you think generating full html in servlet manually is a bad idea??? Rather then what you should do is make a `JSP` for that

Answer (score 0):

Be sure about the address. It can be, if testing locally in Eclipse for instance,

*http://localhost/[project-name]/[url-pattern]*

or

*http://localhost:8080/[project-name]/[url-pattern]*

(verify your server configuration - is it Tomcat?)

Provide a bit more info, for instance the web.xml file is the place were 404 errors come from in case like this.

Finally, make a test with a simple test.html file outside WEB-INF and directly open it with the browser. This will ensure you that there is not connection/server issues in the way